# Git Vincent Driessen model testing server

Tags: git, testing, branching-and-merging

I am using http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/  As far as I understand, main repo in this model should be a bare repo.

In the blog it is stated that "The repository setup that we use and that works well with this branching model, is that with a central “truth” repo." (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) Does it means central repo should be bare?

Where i can run testing and bug fixing? Is following a best approach?

1) Set up a testing server as clone of central repo.
2) pull from central repo regularly to get new features and bug fixes(for the bugs reported in testing server).
3) Do test and bug fix of big features in developers repo itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "truth" repo I think he only means that everyone agrees it's the central one: any changes, branches, etc. on this repo are the real state of the world. Anything on a developer's individual repo is only their problem. Regardless of whether he means that, the central repository should almost certainly be bare.

Your idea that a testing server should clone the central repo and pull changes before each test run is entirely sensible and normal. Generally, you'll want to run tests on the current release branch, and the 'develop' branch, and probably on the 'master' branch each time you push a change to it. Using `git-bisect`, if someone introduces a defect on a branch between test runs, it's easy to find which commit introduced the error. The testing server will probably have a separate clone of the central repository for each branch you want to build and test, or you could even do that on separate testing servers if necessary.